# How much would AWS ec2 cost for a project of my type

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have tried many times to install the R server on an AWS instance using terminal commands without any luck. I can install it using http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/ 
 and following a Youtube video but I cannot get the dropbox sync to stop "syncing". I have tried installing a fresh version using the terminal and Putty and other methods without much success.

What I wanted to use AWS for was to use the bandwidth / computing time.

I basically wanted to run an R script to download a bunch of documents which could take 2 weeks to download. I had hoped to save these on a large dropbox account I have access to but unfortunately `library("RStudioAMI")
linkDropbox()
excludeSyncDropbox("*")` doesn`t seem to work for me and the whole dropbox folder gets synced onto my AWS instance and I run out of space.

So basically... I think I will forget dropbox and just use AWS storage.

I want to download appox 500GB - or perhaps 1TB worth of data (running an R script to download documents and save them), it just connects to a website and downloads a document, so no ML or high computing power needed. Just a consistent connection. Once the documents are fully downloaded I would like to then just transfer them to an external hard drive I have for further analysis.

So my question is, "approximately" how much do you think this may cost, I don't care about paying 20-30$ I just don`t want to go in with inexperience/without knowledge and rack up hundreds$.

Additionally: What other instances/servers do you suggest I pay for, I feel like I dont need that much power just consistency.

Here is another SO question I opened:

[Amazon AWS Dropbox link error: "No directories are being ignored."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029246/amazon-aws-dropbox-link-error-no-directories-are-being-ignored)

Comment: You can use: https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Comment: not a question ot stack overflow in my opinion but you can check here  https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Comment: Thanks, I have already looked at this but my background is not really in computer hardware (its economics) so I have no idea really what I am reading on that site... How many `Elastic IP Remaps` do I need for my problem, `Intra-Region Data Transfer`? - I just want to download data.

Answer (score 1):

There will be three main costs for your scenario:

- **Amazon EC2**, which is charged hourly. You do not need much processing power, so a `t3.small` would probably be adequate if you're not doing any big computations. It's only about 2c/hour, which is $7 for 2 weeks.
- An **Amazon EBS disk volume** attached to your Amazon EC2 instance for storing the data. A General Purpose volume is 10c/GB/month. So, 1TB for 2 weeks would be $50. If you configure it to use "Cold HDD (sc1)", then it's a quarter of that price.
- **Data Transfer** for when you download *from* AWS. If you are using AWS in the USA, it is 9c/GB. So, 1TB = $90. This would be your major cost.

There might be some other minor costs, but they won't be significant compared to the above.

Or, given that your basic goal is to collect and download data, you could just do it on a computer at home.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! The problem with the computer at home is that I need the laptop and dont have a dedicated omputer to do the job. I have a computer at the university but I am hardly ever there and if something goes wrong with the R code I would like to be able to observe this and correct it. AWS synced with my dropbox account seemed like the perfect solution, but I cannot get this working...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not strictly limited to EC2 ( which I think you are not, considering the requirement you stated and the AMI approach failed for you) , AWS Lightsail would be a much better solution

It has bundled data transfer package and acceptable performance

Here is the 1-month plan

```
512 MB Memory
1 Core Processor
20 GB SSD Disk
1 TB Transfer ( Data in will cost nothing, only data Out, Ex: From LightSail to your local PC )
Additional SSD - $10 for 1 TB
```

Average network performance for that instance I see is about 30 Megabyte per second. You can just shutdown everything and only billed for the hours you used in the month